# Retrieve typeid of shared_ptr deleter?

Tags: c++, stl, type-erasure

(For background info, it *might* help to read [shared_ptr without RTTI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180899/shared-ptr-without-rtti) first. Or it might not.)

I'm looking at the interface for `shared_ptr` out of curiosity — that is, this question is *not* motivated by a real use-case, but just questioning whether I'm missing something. I see that `shared_ptr` does type-erasure of its deleter, similarly to `std::any` and `std::function`. In the latter two cases the Standard always gives us a pair of type-*unerasure* functions: one that tells the exact `typeid` of the erased object, and one that reveals the original object iff we can guess its original type at compile time (and if not, ["go fish!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Fish#The_game)).

```
int xx = 42;
using Type = decltype(xx);
std::any a = xx;
assert( a.type() == typeid(Type) );
assert( std::any_cast<Type>(a) == 42 );

int (*xx)() = +[]() { return 42; };
using Type = decltype(xx);
std::function<long()> f = xx;
assert( f.target_type() == typeid(Type) );
assert( *f.target<Type>() == xx );

void (*xx)(int *) = +[](int *x) { delete x; };
using Type = decltype(xx);
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int, xx);
/* assert( ??? == typeid(Type) ); */
assert( *std::get_deleter<Type>(p) == xx );
```

The crazy different spellings of these type-unerasure accessors I take as par for the course. What really surprises me, though, is that there doesn't seem to be any "get the `typeid`" accessor for `shared_ptr`! Am I just missing something on cppreference? Or is there a technical reason this particular function would be difficult to provide? Or is it just a random hole in the specification of `shared_ptr`, i.e., historical reasons?

(Again, I can't think of any use-case for this, and IMHO it would be preferable if neither `function` nor `shared_ptr` allowed type-unerasure at all; but since they *do*, I'm wondering why it's so dang inconsistent.)

Comment: Side note: the unary plus on those lambdas is not necessary for pointer conversion.

Comment: From the looks of it, it's go-fish to get the type of the deleter for shared_ptr. I don't know of a technical reason why there cannot be a get_deleter function that returns a `std::type_info` like `std::function` as you pointed out. Agreed it seems like it could be rectified to do as much.